# 16.04 no HDMI audio out option

Tags: nvidia, sound, 16.04, asus, hdmi

I have read every other thread on this and I can't find a fix.  I have an Asus Zenbook UX51V - built in Nvidia 650m graphics (where the HDMI comes from).  I have selected the Nvidia drivers in the "Additional Drivers" section.  The audio codec is Realtek ALC668. I have installed Pulse/Alsa... uninstalled both, and reinstalled both to no avail.  The only thing different now is I don't have a volume option in my top right menu(where you select system settings) and in Pulse Audio I can't test my speakers anymore(it just doesn't work for some reason) tho audio does work from my speakers in all other situations.  In PAVC there is no HDMI option to choose from, only speakers and headphones. Oh... video thru the HDMI to the TV works perfectly.  WTF

Comment: Really.... no one has anything on this?  How can such a basic feature simply not work?  Without HDMI audio out Ubuntu is virtually useless for my needs.  It would be great if someone could help out on this.